How to decouple the Lennard-Jones (LJ) interaction between two particular atoms in a same molecule?
I would like to decouple the lennard-jones (LJ) interaction between two atoms of the same molecule. These atoms obviously doesn't have any bonded interactions between them, so only the non-bonded interactions. Is it possible to do that with GROMACS? Thanks

If the atoms are 3 or 4 atoms apart, then simply adding the nrexcl to the topology file is the way. nrexcl = 3 excludes non-bonded interactions between atoms that are no further than three bonds away. If not, Extra exclusions within a molecule can be added manually in a [ exclusions ] section in the topology file. Each line should start with one atom index, followed by one or more atom indices. All non-bonded interactions between the first and other atoms will be excluded.

Thanks @Vasista, but the whole idea is to decouple the LJ interactions between these two particles over lambda from 0 to 1 at some intervals. So, when lambda is equal to 0, there will be a strong LJ interaction, and with the increase in lambda value, the LJ interaction vanishes.
